# Unable to fix cannot fix properties of null(setting:innerText) error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write the output I got to a paragraph defined as `<p id="output-text"></p>` in my html file. However I keep getting an error that says `Uncaught:TypeError:Cannot set properties of null(setting:innerText)`. What can I do to fix this?
I tried checking if there is a difference in the `id` is used in my HTML file and the 'id' I used
to reference it in the `.js` file . I don't find any difference in that aspect.

```
const dob=document.querySelector("#dob");
const luckyNumber=document.querySelector("#lucky-num");
const checkButton=document.querySelector("#check");
checkButton.addEventListener("click",clickHandler);
const result=document.querySelector("#output-text");

function clickHandler()
{
    var sumOfDigits=sum(dob);
    testLuck(sumOfDigits,luckyNumber);
}

function sum(dob)
{
    dob=dob.value.replaceAll("-","");
    console.log(dob);
    dob=parseInt(dob);
    var sum=0;
    while(dob > 0)
    {
        var digit=dob%10;
        sum+=digit;
        dob=Math.trunc(dob/10);
    }
    return sum;
}

function testLuck(sumOfDigits,luckyNumber)
{
    if(sumOfDigits%luckyNumber.value === 0)
    {
        result.innerText="YayyYour Birthday is Lucky";
    }
    else
    {
        result.innerText="Uff your Birthday is not sooo lucky it seems";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you loading the script before or after the DOM has loaded? That code should work but only if it has access to the fully-loaded DOM.

Comment: To make sure that your script is run after page load use `defer`, like this: `<script src="/path-to-file" defer></script>`

Comment: Oh my! Yes it is now fixed. That was very silly of me. Thank you :)